# Properly map values between two dataframes

Tags: pandas, dataframe, mapping

I have dataframe `df`

```
d = {'Col1': [10,67], 'Col2': [30,10],'Col3': [70,40]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

which results in

```
    Col1    Col2    Col3
0     10    30       70
1     67    10       40
```

and `df2`

```
df2=pd.DataFrame(data=([25,36,47,(0,20)],[70,85,95,(20,40)],
[12,35,49,(40,60)],[50,49,21,(60,80)],[60,75,38,(80,100)]),
columns=["Col1","Col2","Col3","Range"])
```

which results in:

```
     Col1   Col2    Col3    Range
0     25    36       47    (0, 20)
1     70    85       95    (20, 40)
2     12    35       49    (40, 60)
3     50    49       21    (60, 80)
4     60    75       38    (80, 100)
```

Both frames are just for example purposes and might be much bigger in reality. Both frames have the same columns but one.

I want to apply some function (x/y) between each value from `df` and a value in `df2` from the same column. The value from `df2` however maybe in varying rows depending on the `Range` column.

For example 10 from `df (Col1)` falls in range (0,20) in `df2` therefore I want to use 25 from `Col1 (df2)` and do 10/25.

30 from `df (Col2)` falls in range (20,40) in `df2` therefore I want to take 85 from `Col2 (df2)` and do 30/85.

70 from `df (Col3)` falls in range (60,80) in `df2` therefore I want to take 21 from `Col3 (df2)` and do 70/21.

I want to do this for each row in df.

Don't really know how to do the proper mapping; I always tend to start with some for loops which are not very pretty especially if both dataframes are of bigger shape. Expected output can be any array, dataframe or the like composed of the resulting numbers.

Comment: does your actual df merge on ranges (numerical) or is it just an example?

Comment: I don't understand the logic of determining which column from `df2` you will use. Other question; is your DF1 in reality also just 1 row?

Comment: I revised the main body text. Columns in both frames are with the same headers so I want to use values from corresponding columns. The actual frames can be much bigger - df is not just one row but more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do it by defining a helper function:

```py
def find_denominator_for(v):
    """Helper function.
    >>> find_denominator_for(10)
    {'Col1': 25, 'Col2': 36, 'Col3': 47}
    """
    for tup, sub_dict in df2.set_index("Range").to_dict(orient="index").items():
        if min(tup) <= v <= max(tup):
            return sub_dict


for col in df.columns:
    df[col] = df[col] / df[col].apply(lambda x: find_denominator_for(x)[col])
```

Then:

```py
print(df)
# Output

   Col1      Col2      Col3
0  0.40  0.352941  3.333333
1  1.34  0.277778  0.421053
```